# how to edit session variable when loading a different controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables

HI i am using codeigniter , i have controller settings ,

there i set some session variables .

```
$this->ci->session->set_userdata('lob_data',$lob_data);
```

i want to set

```
 $this->ci->session->set_userdata('lob_data',array());
```

when i go to any other controller than settings .

but i don't want to reset variable when i reload the settings controller.

how to do this ,

thanks in advance .......

Comment: Why do you want to remove the data when leaving the page? Wouldn't it just be easier to keep the data in the session?

Comment: @jrConway , no i don't want to keep that data :)

Comment: I'm just not sure why you don't want to keep that data. It shouldn't affect much unless you've got tons of variables set in the session data. Also, you should probably use  $this->ci->session->unset_userdata('lob_data');

Comment: I'm not sure how to save the data, get it out of the session variable, and then get the same data back again barring saving the data to the database. The purpose of using session is to preserve data across your whole visit to the website. Unless you simply mean that you don't want to repeat set_userdata on every page, in which case add it to your base controller and check what page you are on. If you're interested in this idea I can write up the syntax in a proper answer.

Comment: @jrConway i think you did not get my point , the thing is i am making some changes in settings controller , when i go to another controller , i want to undo those changes , but when i reload settings controller , i don't want to undo changes.

Comment: "Changes" doesn't really help. I don't know what the context is. You should explain better what you are trying to do. I don't even know what setting the session has to do with making changes to the settings controller.

Answer (score 0):

it looks ridiculous,but try something like :

```
$this->ci->session->set_userdata('lob_data',empty($this->ci->session->set_userdata('lob_data',$lob_data)));
```